# Graphic Is Not Adding to The Exact Snapping Point

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can you please take a look at [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6uweoank/) and let me know why the added graphic to the snapping feature is not exactly added on top of the feature.
Please try the fiddle and add a Point to the map by CTL key . after zooming the graphic you will notice the point is added to position of the cursor instead of Snapped point.

```
var map;

require(["esri/map",
  "esri/SnappingManager",
  "esri/toolbars/draw",
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/graphic",
  "esri/Color",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
  "dojo/keys",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Map, SnappingManager, Draw, FeatureLayer, Graphic, Color, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, keys) {
  map = new Map("map", {
    basemap: "topo",
    center: [-88.158805, 41.786075],
    zoom: 18
  });
  var sms = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_DIAMOND, 12,
    new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([70, 0, 130, 1]), 1), new Color([70, 0, 130, 1]));
  var propertyLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/CommunityAddressing/FeatureServer/0", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["*"]
  });
  map.addLayers([propertyLayer]);

  $("#add").on("click", function() {
    var toolbar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map);
    toolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.POINT);
    map.on("click", addGraphic);

    function addGraphic(evt) {
      var graphic = new Graphic(evt.mapPoint, sms);
      map.graphics.add(graphic);
      console.log(evt.mapPoint);
    }

  });


  propertyLayer.on("mouse-over", function(evt) {
    //console.log("Snapped")
  });
  var snapManager = map.enableSnapping({
    snapKey: keys.CTRL,
    tolerance: 50,
  });
  var layerInfos = [{
    layer: propertyLayer
  }];
  snapManager.setLayerInfos(layerInfos);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that you were using the mouse point to insert the graphic, instead of the snapping point. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/katah/6uweoank/2/) the code to use the snapping point:

```
var map;

require(["esri/map",
  "esri/SnappingManager",
  "esri/toolbars/draw",
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/graphic",
  "esri/Color",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
  "dojo/keys",
  "dojo/Deferred",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Map, SnappingManager, Draw, FeatureLayer, Graphic, Color, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, keys, Deferred) {
  map = new Map("map", {
    basemap: "topo",
    center: [-88.158805, 41.786075],
    zoom: 18
  });
  var sms = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_DIAMOND, 12,
    new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([70, 0, 130, 1]), 1), new Color([70, 0, 130, 1]));
  var propertyLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/CommunityAddressing/FeatureServer/0", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields: ["*"]
  });
  map.addLayers([propertyLayer]);

  $("#add").on("click", function() {
    var toolbar = new esri.toolbars.Draw(map);
    toolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.POINT);
    map.on("click", addGraphic);

    function addGraphic(evt) {      
      var deferred = map.snappingManager.getSnappingPoint(evt.screenPoint);
      deferred.then(function(value){
        var point;
        if(value !== undefined){
          point = value;
        } else {
          point = evt.mapPoint;
        }
        console.log(point);
        var graphic = new Graphic(point, sms);
        map.graphics.add(graphic);
      }, function(error){
        console.log('Error');
      });
    };
  });

  propertyLayer.on("mouse-over", function(evt) {
  //console.log("Snapped")
  });
  var snapManager = map.enableSnapping({
    snapKey: keys.CTRL,
    tolerance: 50,
  });
  var layerInfos = [{
    layer: propertyLayer
  }];
  snapManager.setLayerInfos(layerInfos);
});
```

Comment: It's interesting how map.graphics.add(new Graphic(evt.mapPoint, sms)); line can completely break the snapping. https://jsfiddle.net/29pyotvr/